# css animations forwards not persisting on iphone?

Tags: css, animation

I seem to be having an  problem on the iphone with keeping the end state of my animation, I have a fade in on the the text in my header that doesn't seem to persist it's end state, even when adding forwards. Any insight into this?

Here's the css:

```
#headerwrap h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    z-index: 9999;
    animation: fadeInDown 3s forwards;
    -moz-animation: fadeInDown 3s forwards; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 3s forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadeInDown 3s forwards; /* Opera */
}
```

And here's the animation keyframes

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
     0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
     }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        -ms-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}
```

It fixed the problem on desktop, but when I check on my iphone they animations come in, then when they complete the text disappears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed it by removing the transform:none; on the 100% frames.